# Differences between Verb + to be + adjective and Verb + adjective

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs, zero-copula, predicate-adjectives, to-be-deletion

What are the differences between these two sentences?

> *These two guys seem to be inseparable.*
>
> *These two guys seem inseparable.*

I can intuitively say that the latter one is grammatically wrong. Could you please explain?

**EDIT**: What I think is John Lawler's and FumbleFingers' answers are worth the read. The reason why I  noted that someone who wants to learn the answer of this question, accidentally misses FumbleFingers' answer.

Comment: I don't know how to edit the title but it should be _Seem_ instead of _Verb_. This is very far from being true of every verb; _seem_ and _appear_ have extremely strange syntax.

Comment: The question is about *seem* and not just about any verb.  When Tim was five years old, he wanted to be tall. *(good)*  When Tim was five years old, he wanted tall. *(bad)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your intuition is incorrect. They are both grammatical. And they are identical in meaning. The only difference between these two sentences is how many syllables they have.

The cluster *to be*, consisting of the infinitive complementizer *to*, plus the predicate adjective auxiliary infinitive *be*, is frequently deleted after the predicate *seem* (or *appear*) before a predicate adjective, like *inseparable* (meaning  'very close friends'). There is no specific rule saying when to perform this deletion; it's a matter of individual choice, like many other rules in English.

The reason why *to be* can be deleted here is that it has no meaning, and serves merely to mark the complement clause as an infinitive (required **after** *seem*) and the predicate of the complement clause as a predicate adjective (required **before** *inseparable*). So it's dispensable.

There are lots of syntactic rules (which means "processes", btw, and not rules for "Correctness" -- think of them as grammatical apps in your brain) in English that have the effect of shortening, moving, or deleting such frequently-occurring but semantically null chunks, and otherwise make speech faster. And supposedly easier.

Easier for the speaker, anyway. They don't always make things easier for the understander, or the learner, though. Frequently you have to [put all that stuff back into the sentence](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf) to make it clear.

This rule (or app) is [*To-be*-Deletion](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/tobeandnottobe.pdf); a similar one for a different situation is [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971).

Comment: Could you give me an example so that the cluster _to be_ has a meaning and it is indispensable, please? The answer is nice. A little hard for me to understand everything -I am not that much  familiar the terminology. Luckily, we have Wikipedia:)- but I appreciate solid and compherensive answers.

Comment: The first one that comes to mind is _To be, or not to be,_ of course. The _to_ is required because infinitives starting sentences require a complementizer to mark subordination (remove it and see what happens). The _be_ is required because it's the main verb and has an actual meaning -- in this case, human life and experience of existence.

Comment: @Thorn: On a more mundane level, Greta Garbo's *"I want to be alone"* grammatically requires *"to be"*. I think it's just that some verbs (such as *seem, appear, look*) are so close to *be* in meaning that we can dispense with them if we want. But I can't easily explain why with some others *("You sound sad", "You smell bad")* we don't even seem to have that choice at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes yes, After I've just checked everything again, I understand that I was a little bit dizzy yesterday :). I totally comprehend now. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Thorn: I don't know if you've looked at the answer I wrote since that last comment. John says here *"There is no specific rule saying when to perform this deletion [of **to be**]"*, but it now seems to me there *is* a rule in play. Even if so far only one other person (you?) thinks so enough to upvote the proposition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've just seen your answers and now I see this comment. I am confused about what should I do. I like your justification but I've already picked the my 'right choice'.

Comment: @Thorn: If by that you mean you'd like to switch your "accept" tick to a different answer (mine, I'd like to hope), I think you can simply click on your existing green tick and it will be "undone", leaving you free to re-allocate the tick somewhere else. I know that in some situations you can't reverse an "up/down" vote unless the question text has been edited since you last voted on it, but I don't think that restriction applies to "acceptance" votes. Whatever - I have the rep points to make an insignificant edit to John's answer, so I'll do that just to be sure you don't have a problem.

Comment: It's actually unimportant to me whether the accent gets "checked" or not. I'm really just interested in the questions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and John Lawler
I find that it is not ethical. Actually case is not about ethics. When I clicked the right answer button, John's answer satisfied me and there wasn't any better answer so far. I think I couldn't change. I cannot explain clearly and I think both of you are not interested in the karma or point. This is one of the awkward situation I've ever been. Anyway :)
FumbleFingers' answer is also logical and the root of the answer makes sense to me very much. The only problem which I consider is someone who wants to know the answer, couldn't see FumbleFingers' answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think both of answers should be considered and read. I will make an edit of the question then we jump out this awkward situation :). Thank you guys.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I myself originally upvoted your answer, because at first I really did think your assessment was correct and that there's *no specific rule* in play. I still agree the *identical in meaning* part for OP's specific verb "seem" - but unless you convince me otherwise, I think there is a "rule" of sorts *based on cognitive processes*, as OP neatly puts it.

Comment: @Thorn: I think it's fair to say neither John or myself are really interested in points or "fairness" here on ELU. But we are both basically lovers of language (well, only English and a bit of French in my case). And strictly speaking your exact question is fully answered by John saying "both are identical". I've really just used it as a springboard for some totally unsubstantiated theorising about related verbs.

Comment: I think what I meant was that the individual decision by a speaker to omit or not is governed overwhelmingly by the individual speaker's individual decisions, motivations, and goals in emitting the sentence. It's just that there are hundreds, possibly thousands of verifiable _rules_ being applied in such a case, and there can be no single rule that applies in all cases. Au contraire. That's all. Nothing to see here. Move along, please.

Comment: Incidentally, I have run across an electronic version of Ann Borkin's paper on _to be_-deletion (inevitably entitled "To Be and Not To Be"), and [put it on my website](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/tobeandnottobe.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

All verbs relevant to this construction mean something like *"to be"* anyway (i.e. - *"something **is** [actually or possibly] in some state"*). At the risk of crossing swords with the professionals, I disagree with John's assertion that *"There is no specific rule saying when to [omit **'to be'**]"*.

---

(1) Verbs where we *never* use **'to be'** involve more 'primitive' (limbic/visceral?) sensory perception as processed by the hindbrain. Anything perceived by touch/taste/smell/sound is virtually by definition "real", so you don't need to repeat the relationship with reality.

- I **feel** happy.
- This **tastes** great.
- It **smells** awful.
- You **sound** upset.

---

(2) Verbs where **'to be'** is optional are those primarily alluding to sight/visual cortex. But of course, appearances can be deceptive - so maybe including ***to be*** more explicitly conveys that what we're seeing really is "real".

- He **looks** [to be] annoyed. *(some may dislike **'to be'** here)*
- You **seem** [to be] clever.
- They **appear** [to be] friendly. *(some may prefer **'to be'** here)*

---

(3) Verbs where we *always* use **'to be'** involve far more sophisticated mental processing, such as judgement, forward planning, etc. In these cases, the state being spoken of may be only loosely connected with "reality", so we include the auxiliary verb to strengthen that relationship.

- I **want** to be alone.
- She **hopes** to be married.
- He **hates** to be surprised.
- They **like** to be active.

---

That looks like a pretty clear progression to me. It's all about how strongly the verb (and possibly other aspects of the context) imply that the state being spoken of corresponds to irrefutable reality *as we perceive it*. I'd particularly flag up the uncertainty surrounding **look**, where simple "sight" leans towards (1), as opposed to **appear** (involving evaluation), which leans towards (3).

Comment: Thanks this is very nice explanation and I really like your justifications that are based on cognitive processes which I find it as a fascinating area to study :). Sorry for delayed renumeration. (I do not know this word is appropriate)

Comment: I think this is the 'right answer'.

Comment: @Thorn: I'm not sure *"renumeration"* is really a valid English word - usually it occurs as a typo for *"remuneration"* (payment, wages). Better words there might be *reclassification, revaluation, re-evaluation, recategorisation*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are fine. The first states an impression that may be contrary to fact. The second asserts a fact (which may also be open to dispute, but not to the person making the claim). Think of the first  as a softer form of assertion.

Comment: @Fumble: *Seems* seems to be less definite, at least to me, than *is*.

Comment: I assume you don't mean that by writing "**Seems** *seems to be less definite*" you intended to convey less conviction than if you'd simply written "**Seems** *seems less definite*". It seems to me all it shows is that you're more casually dexterous/profligate on the keyboard than me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. It's because the verb "to seem" can function like a normal verb as well as a copulative verb or copula or linking verb. Linking verbs don't describe action in any way, so they are followed by predicative adjectives or noun complements instead of objects. Other verbs, such as "to appear", "to smell", etc., also function both as copula and as normal verbs, as in the following examples:

1. He appeared/looked **dead**.
2. The flowers smelled **nice**.

Note that you never say "The flowers smelled **nicely**".

The verb "to be" is an interesting one, because it's always a linking verb. That's why "to be", in all its forms, is followed by pronouns like "I", "he", "she", and "they", instead of "me", "him", "she", and "them", in traditional, grammatical English. So "It is I", "That would be he", etc. are actually grammatical.

Comment: So what is the rule of thumb? If the verb doesn't describe action in any way, then they want to get adjective not adverb and using _to be_ with them is dispensable?

Comment: With linking words, yes.

Comment: 'Be' is not always a linking verb. Look at all the usages AHDEL lists for the non-auxiliary; not all of them are copular.