# Word order and length of noun phrase

Tags: verbs, word-order

Edwin Williams says [here](https://archive.org/details/trent_0116404281911/page/102) that some verbs in the frame [V NP AP]† like e.g. *wipe* admit NP and AP to invert freely (1) while others like *consider* don't (2a-b): they require NP to be "long" or "heavy" (2c).

> (1a) I wiped the table clean
>
> (1b) I wiped clean the table

> (2a) I consider the table clean
>
> (2b) *I consider clean the table
>
> (2c) I consider clean any table with a reflectant surface

I was wondering if *appoint*/*elect* behave like *wipe* or like *consider* in this respect. Are (3b) and (4b) OK?

> (3a) We appointed a burly man captain of the team
>
> (3b) We appointed captain of the team a burly man

> (4a) We elected an old woman vicepresident of the board
>
> (4b) We elected vicepresident of the board an old woman

†Abbreviations: V = verb, NP = noun phrase, AP = adjectival phrase.

Answer (score 3):

(1) and (2) have different structures. They're not "in the frame [V NP AP]"; they're quite different. Constructions are not beads on a string; they have internal structure. (3) and (4), on the other hand, are the same and are both grammatical, if awkward.

(1a-b) are examples of a fixed verbal construction *[wipe clean]*, functionally a phrasal verb like *[cook down]* or *[blow up]*, which can undergo [Dative alternation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/106899/15299):

- *He **wiped** the table **clean** ~ He **[wiped clean]** the table*.
- *He **cooked** the greens **down** ~ He **[cooked down]** the greens.*
- *They **blew** the balloon **up** ~ They **[blew up]** the balloon.*

(2) is different. *Consider clean* is not a fixed phrase, but rather a string that results from a different rule, [*to be*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57088/15299). (2a) comes from an original complement clause which things have been done to:

- *I consider [(for) the table (to be) clean].*

The *for* part of the *for...to* infinitive complementizer is deleted, as it usually is, and the required and therefore noninformational *to be* [is also deleted](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/tobeandnottobe.pdf), followed by Subject Raising moving *the table* up to become object of *consider*, whence it can be passivized into

- *The table is considered clean (by me)*.

Note that *to be*-Deletion is optional, so at any stage one can add *to be* without change in meaning:

- *I consider the table to be clean.*
- *The table is considered to be clean.*

This is a fact about *consider*, not about "[V NP AP]". Lots of verbs work like *consider*, so it's hardly unique. Those two constructions just look the same on the surface.

*Appoint* and *elect* are odd 3-place predicates with two objects but no receiver or trajector. Instead, the two objects refer to two different identities that have been merged - one usually personal and the other official, though both can be official, like *He appointed the Duke of Denver as his Official Representative*.

All the sentences given in (3-4) are strange, because the point of the construction is to identify one participant and link them with the new title. That means one part should be short and the other part should be long. In these sentences both parts are long and the construction bursts its tethers. Don't try to be precise and also fully descriptive in the same sentence.

One thing that may be helpful in handling these constructions is that one can always insert *as* before the newly-acquired role, thus identifying the person and the role.

Comment: Is *Voters elected Biden president* not uncontroversially idiomatic?

Comment: It's not idiomatic, though using _voters_ instead of generic _they_ is a bit odd.