# "Get used" vs "got used"

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past

I'm learning English grammar with the book by Raymond Murphy: *English Grammar in Use [3rd Edition]*. In the exercises for unit 61, I have to complete the sentences using *used to*. I can't understand why I have to say *get used to living* instead of *got used to living* for this example:

> Sue moved from a big house to a much smaller one. She found it strange at first. She had to ***_*__*_*__*_*___** in a much smaller house.

Is it past simple or past perfect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see why this would be confusing.

> - She would have to get used to living in a smaller house.
> - She had to get used to living in a smaller house.
> - She had gotten used to living in a smaller house.
> - She got used to living in a smaller house.

All of these are acceptable.  Each has a slightly different time reference; the first one is looking ahead, and the last two are looking back.

As Brett indicated, the problem with the one in the book (*had to got used to*) is you don't use "*got*" after "*to*".

Answer (score 8):

Following *to,* the verb is in the infinitive and has no tense. So you should use the base form: *get.* Nor is this the perfect. Here, the *had* is part of the idiomatic *have to,* meaning that there was no option but to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

There's three (possibly four) different English constructions that contain the string *used to*.

One (possibly two) is (possibly are) the simple past participle *used* /yuzd/ plus the complementizer /to/ for a following purpose infinitive

a) *The shovel in the garage is **used to** dig with.*

b) *The shovel **used to** dig with is in the garage.*

**Note** -- both (a) and (b) are pronounced /yuzdtu, yuztu, yuzdtə/, or /yuztə/, with a voiced **/z/**.

Some might consider (a) and (b) different constructions, but I would consider (b) just a [*Whiz*-deleted relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971), derived from *The shovel **(which is) used to** dig with...* That's what I meant above by "(possibly four)." How one counts depends on what one believes one is counting.

The other two constructions containing *have to* are both idiomatic, which means, in this case, that

- both idioms have special meanings

  - one (c) means "accustomed to" and the other (d) means "perfective generic or stative"
  - c) *I'm not **used to** typing on this new keyboard yet.*
  - d) *I **used to** type on a Dvorak keyboard.*
- both have special grammar

  - (c) *used to* is a predicate adjective,
  - (c) *used*  requires a preceding *be*
  - (c) *to* is a regular preposition, not an infinitive complementizer
  - (c) *used to* can take a gerund complement, but not an infinitive
  - *They **are** used to him/late lunches/Mexican food/taking risks/sleeping late.*
  - (d) *used to* is a real auxiliary verb
  - (d) *used to* requires an infinitive complement
  - (d) *used to* has no tense (rather, it **functions** as a tense)
  - (d) *used to* presupposes its complement to be false in the present, though true in the past.
  - *They **used to** like him/eat late lunches/like Mexican food/take risks/sleep late.*
- both (c) and (d) have (the same) special pronunciation

  - both idioms fuse the string *used to* into a single word (/yustə/ occasionally /yustu/),
  - both idioms **always** pronounce this with voiceless /s/, **never** with voiced /z/.
  - both idioms disallow (or at least disapprove of) separation of the *used* and the *to*
  - *Occasionally, when the spirit moved him, he used to walk over and buy a beer.*
  - **He used, occasionally, when the spirit moved him, to walk over and buy a beer.*

(If you think you find this last example grammatical, consider whether you're pronouncing "used ... to" as /yus...tə/ or /yuzd ... tə/ or /yust ... tə/. None of these **sound** write; this is one construction that occurs practically only in writing, and then only for readers who don't hear what they're reading in their mind's ear.)

Comment: Awesome, I was about to ask a question but your post is more than complete that I got the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it´s an old post, but I found the same line in the book ....

Take a look :

- We have got used to
- We had got used to
- We had to get used to

The "had" of last sentence IS NOT working as a "perfect tense". Is just simple past.
The meaning is different. The last sentence is an obligation (WE HAD TO!!)

The first and second HAVE and HAD are working as a "perfect tense".

Bye... Pablo