# Relative Clause Removal of "Relative Pronoun"

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

So I have a grammar book that says you can remove relative pronoun when it is used in defining relative clause, if it is non-defining you can't.

For example:

> The man who we met yesterday was a sales representative.
>
> The man we met yesterday was a sales representative.

both correct. But:

> My father, who you met yesterday, lives in Germany.

According to the book you can't remove "who" from this sentence. Is this acceptable for all cases or just particular ones?

Comment: The book is correct that you can't remove "who" from the example with a non-defining (appositive) relative clause.

Comment: You can't *just* remove *who*, but it can easily be removed: *My father, you met him yesterday, lives in Germany.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book has it right, except for one further condition: you cannot remove the relative pronoun when it functions as the subject of the relative clause.

So:

> *The man [who] we met yesterday...* - "who" is optional. But
>
> *The man who came to see us yesterday...* - "who" is required.

Comment: Or if the pronoun is *whose*.

Comment: The man [whom] we met yesterday - Here, 'man' is an object; 'we' the subject. (We met the man)

Comment: The man who came to see us yday...Here, the man is 'subject'. That answers where 'who' is required.

Answer (score 2):

The rule you cite is mostly true, but it's not complete, because just mentioning "relative pronouns" doesn't distinguish between

1. *wh*-words like *who* and *which*, on the one hand, which can occur with all relative clauses,
   and
2. *that*, which can occur only on [restrictive (integrated, defining) relative clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/345063/15299),

- *The man **whom** we met yesterday was a sales representative.*
- *The man **who** we met yesterday was a sales representative.*
- *The man **that** we met yesterday was a sales representative.*
- *The man **Ø** we met yesterday was a sales representative.*

But *that* can't occur on [non-restrictive (supplementary, non-defining) relative clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/493122/15299),
(in what follows, ungrammatical English sentences are *marked with asterisks)

- *The chairman, **who(m)** we met yesterday, was once a sales representative.*
- *The chairman, **who** we met yesterday, was once a sales representative.*
- **The chairman, **that** we met yesterday, was once a sales representative.*
- **The chairman, **Ø** we met yesterday, was once a sales representative.*

Non-restrictive relative clauses also bar relative pronoun deletion,
as the last ungrammatical sentence shows.

The rule also doesn't distinguish between most relative pronouns  and those relative pronouns -- either *that* or *wh*-word --
that are the **subject** of their relative clause. Subject relative pronouns are also immune to deletion; English tensed clauses require a subject, and this requirement overrides.

- *The man **who** met us yesterday was a sales representative.*
- *The man **that** met us yesterday was a sales representative.*
- **The man **Ø** met us yesterday was a sales representative.*