# When is the omission of relative pronouns acceptable?

Tags: relative-pronouns, omissibility

So I learned that I tend to forget and unconsciously omit relative pronouns from my sentences, because apart from the fact that the meaning of some clauses without them remain clear and obvious, I find that relative pronouns make sentences superfluous.

Instead of writing *“the meat **that** are chilling in the freezer are spoiled”*, I write *“the meat chilling in the freezer are spoiled.”* Or, *“I believe it's true”* instead of *“I believe **that** it's true.”*

I find that many people do this, too. At first, I thought it's grammatically incorrect and is not acceptable in formal writing, but I recently came across a professional article that did the same thing. I'm just wondering whether it was a mistake or the editors deliberately left it that way because it's not really incorrect.

So my question is, is the omission of relative pronouns acceptable? Or better yet, are relative pronouns always necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative pronouns "where" and "when": where can they be omitted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432219/relative-pronouns-where-and-when-where-can-they-be-omitted)

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462434/relative-clause-removal-of-relative-pronoun?rq=1