# Missing "the" - on the official page without any reason

Tags: articles, definite-articles, zero-article

From [the official Autodesk page](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Inventor-Help/files/GUID-06B9592A-E134-44AD-BCA5-8EAD19A0181F-htm.html):

> Create or open a document with **the** styles you want to copy to the style library.

From [the official For Dummies page](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/creating-and-managing-word-2019-templates/):

> Create a new document or open a document with styles that you can recycle. (Without **the** in front of **styles**.)

It seems Dummies version is an error, isn't it?

Another option is that both versions are correct, with a  subtle difference in the assumed meaning. But I really don't see any difference in the context of these examples, and therefore one of them should be wrong (to my opinion).

Comment: No, not an error.  Can I assume that the OP is not a native speaker of English?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, English isn't my native language.

Comment: In case English is not your native language, you may often get more understandable explanations at ell.stackexchange.com that you get here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case the styles are known to the reader, in the second one they're not.

> Create or open a document with the styles you want to copy to the style library.

"*Styles you want to copy*" are predetermined in this context (since these are the ones you want to copy to the style library), and thus this sentence uses the definite article '*the*'.

> Create a new document or open a document with styles that you can recycle.

Here, the dependent clause is "*styles that you can recycle*". Adding the definite '*the*' would suggest that these styles are known in advance, or that they are limited, and different from *styles that you cannot recycle*. Using no article implies generality.

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, but I'm not sure I really understand it. I mean that from the context of the Dummies example it follows that styles are known to the reader.

Comment: In that second case, you are asked to 'open a document with styles you can recycle, or open a new document'. The 'styles you can recycle' don't matter in this case, they can be any style (whereas in the first sentence these are the particular styles that you as a user would want to copy in the first place).

Answer (score -2):

"The" as Joachim alludes to, is the definite article - a specific thing or things.

Whilst the inclusion of 'THE' is more correct and precise - if the thing is known -  I think one can also use the second form without creating a [schism](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/schismhttps://) in the english-speaking world; most people will 'hear' the 'THE', or will understand the implication, if the Thing is known or specific.

Comment: Well, "alludes to".. spells out, really :)

Comment: Why use one word when a thousand will do...

Comment: Because of pictures?

Comment: I think you make my point for me...