# On the structure of "search for weapons and bands of pro-Hussein fighters still holding out"

Tags: meaning, grammar, subjects, syntactic-analysis, whiz-deletion

I came across the following expression:

> The primary task of many American troops in Baghdad has been to search for weapons and bands **of pro-Hussein fighters still holding out**.

This is from a newspaper called *The Japan Times*, which is published in Japan.

I don't understand the structure of the bold part.

1. Is "holding out" a gerund?
2. If so, is "pro-Hussein fighters" its semantic subject?
3. Then, how is this sentence different from "weapons and bands **which/that** pro-Hussein fighters still hold out"?

Comment: The rephrase would actually be 'for weapons, and for bands of pro-Hussein fighters still holding out'.

Answer (score 4):

*To hold out* here means ‘to maintain resistance, remain unsubdued; to continue, endure, persist, last.’ *Holding out* is the non-finite *-ing* form of the verb. A paraphrase would be ‘pro-Hussein fighters who continue to offer resistance.’

Comment: Thank you. But I want to know the grammatical structure of this sentence. I think that its underlying structure is "pro-Hussein fighters still hold out weapons and bands". If this sentence has the paraphrase as you suggest, what is the structure after "search for"?

Comment: No, they are not holding out weapons and bands. ‘Hold out’ in this sense is intransitive. ‘Weapons and bands’ is the object of ‘search for’, post-modified by ‘of pro-Hussein fighters still holding out’.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Is it possible to modify a noun (phrase) in the way like that? "-ing" is the (present) participle? What does  this "of" mean? Is there any other example of this "of"? Is the structure "of + Semantic Subject + Participle"?

Comment: Yes, it happens all the time. ‘Lots of people speaking’, ‘crowds of people cheering’, ‘teams of footballers playing’ . . .

Comment: . . . and a partridge in a pear tree.

Comment: Thank you, Barrie England. In "lots of people" or "crowds of people", "lots of" or "crowds of" is one phrase. if the sentence I asked about is the same as them, it follows that "bands of pro-Hussein" is one phrase. AH, I see!! "still holding out" modifies "bands of pro-Hussein". I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The boldfaced part is a noun phrase with a reduced [relative clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html). It's another case of [*Whiz*-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299). The original was something like

- *... bands of pro-Hussein fighters **who/which/that are** still holding out.*

where *Whiz*-deletion, as is its wont, deleted the boldfaced part -- the *Wh*-word subject of the relative clause, and the auxiliary *be* of the progressive construction that follows it. This is very normal behavior for English.

So, in order, the questions:

1. *Holding out* is **not** a gerund; rather, it's what's left of the progressive construction after *are* got deleted, namely the present active participle (the *-ing* form) of the intransitive phrasal verb *hold out*.
2. The subject of *(are) holding out* is *who/which/that*, which got deleted. This relative pronoun, however, is **coreferential** to its antecedent, *pro-Hussein fighters*, so it means the same. But the (deleted) relative pronoun is the real subject of the relative clause.
3. This sentence is *not* different from a full, untransformed relative clause. It's just that English often deletes predictable syntactic markers to make things shorter; they mean the same and they work the same. Generally the full clauses are considered somewhat more formal, but not always.