# Non verbal predicates in English

Tags: syntactic-analysis, copular-verbs, predicate-adjectives

Is a non-verbal predicate a synonymous term for "nominal predicate"? And moreover, do non-verbal predicates only appear with linking verbs or can also appear in other types of constructions?

I acknowledge definitions of concepts, because I isn't clarified :)

Comment: Please give examples of what you mean by “nonverbal predicate”, and perhaps where you found that term.

Comment: Non-verbal predicates are predicates that are not verbs. Like _I'm tired_ and _He's a doctor._

Comment: @John Lawler: oic. I imagined it might be a of "non-spoken word" kind of predicate, like *"Fancy popping upstairs for a bit of [two-tone rise-fall whistle]?"* (where in UK English that whistle loosely translates as [how's your father](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1588619) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers In that case [tweedle] would be a non-verbal nominal object of a preposition.

Comment: @JohnLawler That’s what I would have thought, but apparently that is not what the OP was thinking of.

Comment: Really? How can one tell?

Answer (score 4):

There are two major kinds of non-verbal [predicates](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) in English:

1. predicate adjectives ("adjectival predicates", if you prefer that construction)
2. predicate nouns ("nominal predicates").

Both types require an auxiliary *be*, though this often gets wiped by [*Whiz* Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) or some other clause-reduction rule. In addition, singular count nouns serving as predicates require an article.

- *He **is** tired.*
- *He **is a** doctor.*
- *This stuff **is** just mud.*
- *He got tired = He came to **be** tired* (inchoative of *be*)
- *They made him a teacher = They caused him to come to **be** a teacher* (causative of *be*)

There are many kinds of constructions, like the last two, where non-verbal predicates can occur without an auxiliary *be*, but they always refer back to a full form which contains *be*.

Predictable auxiliaries like *be* are used just to hold the tense, so in an untensed infinitive or gerund, or in a reduced relative clause, where tense is either irrelevant or already specified by the matrix verb, the *be* usually gets deleted.

Especially for adjective predicates, this is the norm, and it's reasonable to assume that any attributive adjective is reduced from a relative clause with a predicate adjective by *Whiz*-Deletion and adjective-preposing.

- *the old man ~ the man `Wh- is` old*

Comment: In the sentence: "The book is on the table", we have also a non-verbal predicate? How is the name of the complement in this case?

Comment: @Peregring-lk:  Assuming that by "complement" you refer to the prepositional phrase _on the table_, it's a locative adverbial prepositional phrase, and it's the predicate of the sentence, whence the _be_. _"Predicate"_ is a **logical** phenomenon, not a grammatical one. (See [the logic guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for terminology and use) The _be_, on the other hand, is a **grammatical** phenomenon; it's necessary to hold the tense. (See [the Verb Phrase guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) for terminology and use)

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 types of non-verbal predication across languages.

- Equative ~ That guy is my father.
- Proper Inclusion ~ He is a lawyer.
- Attributive ~ He is smart.
- Locative ~ The tv is in that classroom.
- Existential ~ There are students here.
- Possession ~ I have a book. or ~ That book is mine. although arguably this could be considered an example of proper inclusion.

So five arguably six of the types of non-verbal predications are accomplished by the copula *be* in English