# Passive auxiliary verb or progressive one?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, passive-voice, progressive-aspect, ing, whiz-deletion

> Uncle Vernon made another funny noise, like a mouse **being** trodden on.
>                  —*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone*

Is ‘being’ a passive auxiliary verb or a progressive one?

Comment: The answer to your question is “Yes, of course.” My questions in turn are what do you think the difference is and why do you think it matters? Does locking down an abstract category somehow improve your understanding, or does it actually hinder it? Have you ever heard of these things simply being called ***-ing*** forms without getting all knickersnitted about participles and passives and gerunds and progressives and auxiliaries?

Comment: Basically what tchrist is saying (and I agree) is that you should stop caring for such details. Unless of course you're becoming a professor teaching English grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, there **is** a difference. But only because -- as usual -- the sentence has been modified by a transformation. Twice. By the same transformation.

The noun phrase in question:

- *another funny noise, like a mouse being trodden on*

consists of the NP *another funny noise*, modified by a reduced nonrestrictive relative clause, which itself contains a reduced restrictive relative clause.
The original NP would be something like

- *another funny noise, [which was] like a mouse [which was] being trodden on*

but both of the entirely predictable *[which was]* parts of these relative clauses have been deleted by [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299), leaving behind only whatever followed the deleted auxiliary forms of *be*.

That's two tensed forms of *be* that **aren't** present (but can be accounted for), plus one *being* that **is** present, for which an account is requested.

> The **first** (nonrestrictive) *Whiz*-deleted *which was* -- in the clause modifying *noise* -- contains just the normal auxiliary *be* required by the predicate adjective phrase *like a mouse being trodden on*. 
>   It's neither Progressive *be* nor Passive *be*, but rather Predicate Adjective *be*.
>
> The **second** (restrictive) *Whiz*-deleted *which was* -- in the clause modifying *mouse* -- **is** in fact the Progressive *be*, as can be seen by the fact that it's immediately followed by the present active participle (the *-ing* form) of the next verb in the auxiliary chain (*being).*
>
> So the **third** *be* form -- *being* -- can't be the Progressive auxiliary. However, since it's followed immediately by the perfect passive participle (the *-ed/-en* form) of the next, and last (and therefore main) verb of the chain (*trodden*), it must be the Passive auxiliary *be*.

The auxiliary chain, and Verb Phrases generally, are explained in the [VP study guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf).
In brief, auxiliaries are not the whole story; the form of the next verb is equally important,
and may be -- as here -- the only structural evidence left after clause reductions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Having encouraged and known about ‘new vision on English’ by your comment, I’ve started to read English syntax books, and now I can understand what you’re saying much better. Once I already said this, and today I add the appreciation. I owe all the knowledge that I’ve chanced to meet to you.