# "The paper on Monday published X" vs. "the paper published on Monday X"

Tags: adverbs, word-order, past-participles

What would be the best position of *Monday* in the following sentence — before or after the verb?

> - The paper on Monday published what the artist called a blunt attack on people’s right to privacy.
> - The paper published on Monday what the artist called a blunt attack on people’s right to privacy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both sentences are completely grammatical.
The differences are in structure and clarity.

The first sentence is normal and unambiguous.

The second sentence has a small [Garden Path](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gardenpath.pdf), since

- *The paper published on Monday*

would normally be interpreted as a constituent, an NP modified by a relative clause reduced by [Whiz-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) from:

- *The paper **which was** published on Monday*

But then one hits the Garden Wall at ***what*** and has to backtrack and restart the parse.

*What* is a *wh*-word that functions as a marker, introducing and identifying the type of the tensed embedded question direct object [complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf) clause (to give it its fully redundant technical name)

- ***what*** the artist called a blunt attack on people’s right to privacy.
  since the details don't matter, let's just reduce this to
- *what X called Y.*

But now *published* is revealed to be a past tense verb with a direct object, and not a reduced participial, so we have to unwind the expected passive clause

- *the newspaper was published on Monday*
  and instead read it as an active transitive clause
- *on Monday the newspaper published what X called Y*.
  (the fact that *newspaper* can function grammatically as either subject
  or object with *publish* is perhaps unfortunate for our parsing routines)

This is only a minor inconvenience, but why create any? There is no obvious reason to move *on Monday* from a natural unambiguous position to one where it creates a potential problem, so this appears to be a counterindicated strategy.

I.e, it's not incorrect; but it's more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Re *the first sentence is unambiguous* ... I'm now trying to decide whether *"The paper on Monday published Part 1, then on Tuesday Part 2"* is inherently "ungrammatical", or just plain "awkward". If it's ungrammatical, how is it structurally different to *"The paper usually fact-checks its stories, but sometimes makes mistakes"*?

Comment: I'd say "awkard". Temporals like _on Tuesday_ can go in a lot of places, depending on rhythm and intonation, and that makes it a speaker's choice. One of the reasons adverbs are so fluid is that they're sort of like gravy and condiments on top of the main food; you never know how much of what kind of information people need to make the connections you want them to. Some people need a lot of salt before they notice a flavor, and others require hot sauce. So it's best left to the individual context. This makes saucing a written sentence a real challenge. Especially out of context.

Comment: That was my inclination. Nevertheless, even though the first sentence is *semantically* unambiguous, it still seems to me that structurally you could choose to either interpret *the paper on Monday* collectively as a single four-word "subject", or as a two-word subject *(the paper)* followed by *on Monday* "adverbially" modifying *published*. Which doesn't really make any difference when all you want to do is understand what the sentence *means*, but I'd have thought it would affect how you'd break it down in a syntax diagram (not something I'm much good at yet! :).

Comment: The thing is that one encounters -- and parses -- the sentence **sequentially**, and that's the way realtime parsing works. In speech it's great because the intonation and rhythm guide the parse; in print it leads to garden paths. Phrase structure diagrams, on the other hand, are for whole sentences perceived as units, which is a very different thing.

Comment: Ooops! Yet again I've been suckered into focussing on the *written* form (since that what we inevitably use here on ELU). In "real" language (i.e. - *speech*) there is no ambiguity, since the speaker's intonation/rhythm will reflect how *he* sees it. I'm a slow learner, but I am gradually getting the message [One of the basic tenets of linguistics is that language is primarily an oral/aural system](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22linguistics%22+%22language+is+primarily+an+oral%22&oq=%22linguistics%22+%22language+is+primarily+an+oral%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.44278877j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Basic, indeed. Easy to forget, as you say, in this medium. But if you think of how you **say** it first, it becomes much easier to perceive the constituents, and constituents are just about everything in syntax.