# Difference between the adjectives and participles

Tags: differences, adjectives

What is the difference between an adjective and a participle

Comment: Suggested migration to [ell.se]

Comment: Your question should be more specific, in what part of adjective and participle are you confused about? Because they are totally different,

Comment: Eg:" This cloth is smoothly worn leather coat", now which is an adjective or a participle

Comment: It seems like _put on hold as off-topic_ here means "I couldn't think of an answer, and I doubt anybody else can, either".

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that *Participle* appears in the canonical Eight Parts of Speech
([Donatus, *Ars Minor*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html)). And *Adjective* doesn't.
Donatus begins by summing up the Parts of Speech ('Partes Orationis'):

> *partes orationis quot sunt? octo.*
>    'How many parts of speech are there? Eight.'
>    *quae? nomen pronomen uerbum aduerbium participium coniunctio praepositio interiectio.*
>    'What (are they)? Noun Pronoun Verb Adverb Participle Conjunction Preposition Interjection.'

As you can see, no Adjectivum.

Roman grammarians considered adjectives to be abstract nouns -- after all, they had the [same declensions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinNouns.pdf). Later, medieval grammarians distinguished between Nomen Substantivum, the Substantive (independent) Noun, and Nomen Adjectivum, the Adjective (modifying) Noun.

Later, Adjectivum became its own pars orationis,
while Participium somehow slipped off the Approved list.

Of course, the canonical Eight don't really work for English; it's not Latin, after all.

So, to answer the OQ:

`Adjective` and `Participle` are not opposed terms, so there isn't a "difference between" them.
'Adjective' refers to a particular usage pattern as a Predicate with auxiliary *be*, as in

- *He is sick ~ She is tired ~ They are tall ~ We are concerned.*

Most adjectives can also occur preceding and modifying nouns, as in

- *a sick man ~ a tired woman ~ tall men ~ concerned people*

which have the same sense as

- *a man who is sick ~ a woman who is tired ~ men who are tall ~ people who are concerned*

before [Whiz-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299).

'Participle', on the other hand, refers to a type of untensed verb form used in constructions. Latin had [4 different participle forms](http://www.slu.edu/colleges/AS/languages/classical/latin/tchmat/grammar/whprax/w23ppl-f.html), which were used constantly, in many idioms and constructions, so it's easy to see why Latin grammarians found it important.

English, however, only has two participles

1. [the "present active participle", or `-ing` form](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) of the verb (*going, sinking, wanting*)
   and
2. the "perfect passive participle", or `-en` form of the verb (*gone, sunk, wanted*)
   using 2 of the 8 remaining [inflectional suffixes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) in English)

Both of these forms have a **lot** of uses.  Many of them modify nouns,
and many of them appear as main predicates with auxiliary *be*:

- Progressive uses the present participle: *I was attending the meeting*
- Passive uses the perfect participle: *He was seen by several people*

And lots of these constructions have been frozen, so that many adjectives
(e.g, *tired, concerned, born, finished, soft-shelled*) are derived from participial forms.

So basically, a participle can be used as an adjective, and an adjective can come from an old participle. That's what it means to say they aren't opposed terms; they overlap big time.