# Complex sentences question

Tags: grammar

I have 2 sentences that I don't understand:

1.) The girl [[sleeping]] in the room is my sister.
2.) People usually can get a sufficient amount of the calcium their bodies [[ need ]] from the food they consumed.

These 2 sentences have one verb already. (is for (1) and get for (2)) why they don't use the same.

And I heard that without the word "That"  I have to use Ving after that, what is it? Where can I find the source to study.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You may be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://english.stackexchange.com/), but in short, you should study [verbals](http://www.towson.edu/ows/verbals.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences have been done things to.
[Put the pieces back together](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf) before you try to parse them.

Here are the full forms, with the bells and whistles put back in (and superfluous phrases snipped):

1. *The [girl [**who is** sleeping in the room]] is my sister.*
2. *People can get enough of the [calcium [**which/that** their bodies need]] from their food.*

(1) is a case of [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) from a relative clause, producing a post-nominal participial clause.
(2) is a case of a dropped non-Subject relative pronoun [*which/that*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html); they're optional, after all.