# "Choose a password [that is] at least 6 characters long" - should I include "that is"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I am not a native English speaker. But I would like to know if the following sentence is correct?

"Choose a password at least 6 characters long."

Or should it be something like "Choose a password that is at least 6 characters long."?

Comment: Your first is fine.

Comment: Either one is OK. The optional [rule of _Whiz_-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) works on relative clauses with relative pronouns as subject and a form of _be_ as the first verb. You can perform it or not, as you please; speaker's choice.

Comment: Number One is fine.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I *almost* didn't click on your link thinking the name was some kind of joke, but am very happy that I did. Great info for us non-linguists!

Comment: Like I say, I don't make up these names. Here's a [more complete list of English syntactic rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf); notice the other names for syntactic rules. They're intended to be mnemonic without being sleep-inducing; don't forget, there are thousands of them, of which these are only a couple hundred. This is also why good linguists always give examples, because terminology is a very weak reed to lean on.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Those are excellent! Thanks! (Though I think you used the best named deletion, I like colon zapping as well.) This would help anyone write more succinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a sentence is repeated often enough, it can be understood if a few words are left out. For example, did you understand the sentence? I'm sure you did.

The sentence is [abridged](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abridged): shortened by condensing. This doesn't mean removing critical elements of a sentence; they are all there.

Abridging does not make the sentence wrong. If it is easily understood, which is the purpose of communication, then it is fine.

Comment: I agree with you, but for a non native speaker,  I think the grammatically correct sentences are to be focused on first.

Comment: @Josh61 - I have no problem with your answer; you can answer as *you* choose. I will do the same, thank you. The OP asked if it was correct; it is. (See comments under the OP's question.)

Comment: I appreciate your comment; it is just to discuss  differences in the use of the English language that we perceive as relevant.

Comment: @Josh61 I don't understand why you put in the proviso 'but for a non native speaker, I think the grammatically correct sentences are to be focused on first' after 'agreeing' with medica, who says that 'Abridging does not make the sentence wrong'. Also, the intended audience here is not people who are just mastering the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You second sentence is correct,  or

*Choose a password of at least 6 characters.*