# Need audio short stories wrote in all tenses

Tags: american-english

First I apologize for my weakness language

Second Sorry if this topic I put it in wrong place

I read in effortlessenglish course for Aj Hoge that the best way to learn Grammer not to study it but read more stories and every one story must be wrote in all tenses

so please anyone can give me links to download a lot of audio & test stories and every one of this stories are wrote in all different tenses

and thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources

Comment: Should be ***written** in all tenses*. [Whiz-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.selectedshorts.org​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​