# another term for "that "

Tags: word-choice, which-that

I was reading a book with the words

> and a smile that tells me that I picked the right one

the two "that" in the sentence makes me uneasy. Is there another term we can use to replace the other?

Comment: You can omit the complementiser usage (between 'me' and 'I'). I wouldn't.

Comment: What @Edwin said (except I probably *would*). Another "solution" to the "not-really-a-problem" would be to replace the first ***that*** with ***which***. But I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @FF: Yes on this one; 'which' is not background enough.

Comment: *The two "that" in the sentence makes me uneasy.*  The solution: get over it. ;-) IOW, get used to it, so that it does not make you uneasy. From your writing it is clear that English is not your first language. As you become more comfortable with it, this usage will no longer make you uneasy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unlike StoneyB [who unerringly and deliberately _would_ do just that](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/tw-a-pragmatic-approach/). I probably wouldn’t automatically use _which_ here either, but if I thought the sentence became a bit halty and jerky because of the doubled _that_, I wouldn’t hesitate to omit the second, change the first to _which_, or do both.

Answer (score 10):

These are not the same *that*. They have completely different usages and grammar.

The first one is a relative pronoun, the subject of, and heading the [relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) modifying *smile*

- *a smile that tells me that I picked the right one*

Since it's the subject, this relative pronoun *that* is not deletable.
However, the relative pronoun *which* can be substituted for *that*, if desired.

- *a smile which tells me that I picked the right one.*

The second one is a complementizer, introducing the [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf)

- *that I picked the right one.*

This complementizer *that*, since it isn't a subject, and doesn't start a sentence, can be deleted

- *a smile which/that tells me (that) I picked the right one.*

Comment: Typically using *which* means a non-restrictive clause. This calls for a comma, such as in *"a smile, which tells me..."* From the meaning of the sentence, I would say that a restrictive clause is called for (via *that*). There are many kinds of smiles and it's *that* specific one that conveyed the message.

Comment: No, _which_ (like other _wh_-words) is frequently used in restrictive clauses as well. What distinguishes non-restrictive clauses is (a) their intonation (represented with commas) and (b) the fact that _that_ cannot be used as a relative pronoun.