# Are nonrestrictive elements considered part of the subject or part of the predicate?

Tags: subjects, syntactic-analysis, predicate

> Wolves, hunted to extinction in Wyoming and Montana in the twentieth century, occupy a vital place in the natural cycle of the area.

In the above sentence, is the nonrestrictive element *hunted to extinction in Wyoming and Montana in the twentieth century* part of the subject, because it expands on the simple subject *wolves*, or part of the predicate, because it contains the verb *hunted* that uses *wolves* as the subject?

Comment: What you're calling a "nonrestrictive element" (not a standard term) is a nonrestrictive relative clause modifying _wolves_ (***which were** hunted to extinction in Wyoming and Montana in the twentieth century*) which. This clause has been reduced to a participle phrase by the application of [Whiz-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299). Since it modifies the subject, the nonrestrictive relative clause is part of the subject noun phrase constituent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wolves, hunted to extinction in Wyoming and Montana in the twentieth century, occupy a vital place in the natural cycle of the area.

A straightforward test for subject-hood is to make a yes/no question and see what inverts with the auxiliary verb:

- **Do** [Wolves, hunted to extinction in Wyoming and Montana in the twentieth century] occupy a vital place in the natural cycle of the
  area?

Here we see that bracketed part of the sentence appearing between the auxiliary *Do* and the main verb *occupy*. This shows the bracketed part of the sentence to be the Subject. It has inverted with *Do*. If we had an emphatic declarative version of the sentence, it would read:

> - [Wolves, hunted to extinction in Wyoming and Montana in the twentieth century] **do** occupy a vital place in the natural cycle of the area.

As the bracketed section is the Subject, it cannot be part of the Predicate.