# What type of clause can this be?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, whiz-deletion

While I was reading a book, I chanced on a clause that I found very odd. It says,

> The sea, *inches beneath me yet too far for my eyes*, buffeted the raft.

At first I thought the italicised part was a nonessential clause, but I was reasonably confident that there would have to be a word *which* before the word *inches* to make it grammatically correct. So my second guess was that it should be a participle clause with “inches… my eyes” being a participle phrase; but then I thought there should be a participle like *being* before the word *inches*.

Which is correct?

Comment: I think the verb is "buffeted."

Comment: Oh, I see, you're looking for the typology of the independent clause. Sorry!

Comment: The ellipsis of *being* would suggest that the parenthetic clause had something to do with the buffeting.  But that does not make good sense, since the visibility of the sea is unrelated to the buffeting. So I'd say it is a supplemental clause, modifying the sea.

Comment: But how can being be omitted? It seems impossible to me.

Comment: @Rio It’s not _being_ that’s omitted, but _which was_. This is very common in English.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Have a look at the answer about whiz-deletion that I linked to in my answer—it has a few examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re correct that it’s a nonessential clause, but that’s rather a semantic and broad type—a participle clause can be nonessential as well, just like more or less any other type of clause can.

The fact that this clause comes after the noun that it modifies (*sea*) means that it is a **postmodifying** clause.

More specifically speaking, since it does not have a verb (the relative pronoun *which* and the copular verbal form *was* have been deleted through [*whiz*-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/47827)) means that it is a **verbless** clause.

The fact that there is an underlying *which is* (which can be restored with no change in meaning) indicates that it is a **relative** clause, and as you have probably noticed, the intonation and semantics of the sentence imply that it is a **non-restrictive** relative clause.

In other words, to use the terminology used by Pieter de Haan on page 81 of his book [*Postmodifying Clauses in the English Noun Phrase: A Corpus-based Study*](https://books.google.dk/books?id=1kWt-ET1HJ8C&lpg=PA76&ots=PHVmcnTJOO&dq=non-finite%20post-modifying%20clause&hl=da&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false), it is a **postmodifying verbless non-restrictive relative clause**.