# No need for an auxiliary verb in a sentence with 'related to'?

Tags: grammar

Can you explain why there is no need for the auxiliary verb `to be` before `related` in the following sentence:

```
Do you have any information related to the book?
```

What kind of grammar rules are applied in situations like this?

Comment: Participles (both present and past) have been employed as adjectives (both before and after the nouns they modify) as long as the language has been written down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WHIZ is the (sort of slangy) name of the rule that optionally deletes "which is" after "information" in your example.  "Related to the book" is the remnant of the original relative clause "which is related to the book" modifying "information".

And that's what happened to the auxiliary verb "is" before "related".

Comment: Could you perhaps include a link to a reference for this rule?

Comment: [_Whiz_-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299).