# How to analyse the nominal group "the man employed by your company"?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, subordinate-clauses

Does it involve the embedded clause "the man [who is employed by your company]" shortened through ellipsis? And if so, is there are rule for dropping the the verb "to be" when using the passive voice?

Comment: Check here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971

Answer (score 1):

Using a participle, without a full clause, to modify a noun is an ancient construction: it does not originate in a full clause from which a verb was later omitted. So it's not ellipsis. It is often referred to as a **participle construction**.

A participle, like *employed* or *employing*, functions externally like an adjective (and internally like a verb), so it can modify a noun. It is usually placed after the noun in this type of construction. It can have typically verbal constituents belong to it, such as *by your company*, as it is a verb internally.

A certain group of linguists calls this "reduction" or a "reduced relative clause": but by that they do not mean to say that there ever was a full clause with *who...was* in there. They just like the term, because they are not fond of historical explanations, nor of comparing English constructions with the same construction in some other language.

Comment: Semantically, participial clauses are similar to relative clauses, cf. _people who live near the site_  ~ _people living near the site_ and _a letter written by my father_ ~ _a letter that was written by my father_ . I've never liked the 'reduced relative clause' hypothesis', since the distinct feature of a relative is the presence of a relative phrase and there is no possibility of the 'reduced' kind containing one (cf *_people who living near the site_, etc.).