# Relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Is this sentence a relative clause?
There is a nice aquarium called blue sky at there..

Because if it's relative clause, it is subjective pronoun and we have to mention ( which is ) at the sentence..

There is a nice aquarium which is called blue sky at there..

Comment: First, *_at there_ is ungrammatical. Just say _there_, no _at_. Second, a whole sentence can't **be** a relative clause; but a sentence can **contain** a relative clause. Third, relative clauses can be reduced by [_Whiz_-deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299), as happened here.

Comment: As mentioned above, drop the word "at"; then at least you'll have a grammatical sentence to work with. To answer your question: no, "called Blue Sky" is not a relative clause; it's a past-participial clause modifying "nice aquarium". But non-finite clauses like this are semantically similar to relatives, cf. _There is a nice aquarium there which is called Blue Sky_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking whether the phrase "called blue sky" is a relative clause. No, it's not. In fact, it's not a clause at all. To be a clause, it would have to have both a subject and a predicate. As you point out, a relative clause begins with a relative pronoun (e.g., "which"). That pronoun serves as the subject.

"Called blue sky" is a participial phrase directly modifying "aquarium." It works in the sentence more or less like an adjective, except that we find it after the noun it's modifying instead of before.