# A comma before "either-or" construction

Tags: punctuation, commas, either-or

Can you please tell me whether it is correct or not to insert a comma before either in this sentence?

"Finally, the populations of Russia and Turkey did not show any alterations (,) either positive or negative."

I am neither a native speaker nor am I savvy in grammar. Hereby, I want to apologize beforehand, if the question will seem a little dumb. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think it *is* correct to put a comma there. The comma separates *Finally, the populations of Russia and Turkey did not show any alterations*, which is the main clause, from *either positive or negative*, which is a *non-defining relative clause* (which adds extra information but can be removed without losing the meaning of the sentence).

Quoting from https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/non-defining-relative-clauses/,

> Commas or parentheses are always used to separate non-defining relative clauses from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: A relative clause. Are you concerned that _either positive or negative_ doesn't contain a verb?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, So you are suggesting that this part of my sentence can not be defined as a clause but still should be preceded with a comma?

Comment: @Felix Arguably, it's a reduced form of << ..., whether the possible alterations would be positive or negative >> (though it's hard to formulate a decent-sounding longer form); the longer form would obviously need a comma. In any case, however we classify this adjunct, it needs a comma.

Answer (score 1):

The comma is correct. It signals a parenthetical (nonessential or nonrestrictive) element.

That means you can leave off *either positive or negative* without affecting the meaning of the sentence; while the phrase drives home the point, it doesn't need to be there:

> *Finally, the populations of Russia and Turkey did not show any alterations.*

These alterations, had they happened, would have been positive or negative, and we can presumably infer this from context without the aid of the phrase.

---

If it helps your understanding, you can consider the phrase to be (in traditional grammar terms) a reduced relative clause. The **full relative clause** would be reduced from something like:

> *Finally, the populations of Russia and Turkey did not show any alterations (**which would have been either positive or negative**).**

It is reduced by omitting the relative pronoun (*which*) and the *to be* verb (*would have been*), leaving the adjectives behind:

> *Finally, the populations of Russia and Turkey did not show any alterations (either positive or negative).*

At [*What is a noun modifying clause?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971) English and Language Usage's "resident" authority, linguist John Lawler, applies the linguistics term *whiz-deletion* to describe the concept:

> The rule called ***Whiz*-Deletion** by linguists (from the fact that
>   it deletes a *Wh*-word plus a form of *be*, quite often *is*; a
>   monosyllabic variant of "*Wh-is* deletion"), when applied to a
>   relative clause, creates a bare verb phrase without a tensed verb, but
>   with whatever is left after the deletion. Any phrase of more than one
>   word simply goes after the noun it modifies. . . . It has long been
>   suspected that all attributive adjectives . . . are the result of
>   reduction of relative clauses.

---

* <sub>Note that this whole exercise would be easier with an example in the positive (e.g. *The populations showed alterations, either positive or negative* reduced from *The populations showed alterations, which were either positive or negative*).</sub>

Comment: Thank you. You were more than helpful! Can you please suggest some linguistic resources or books that are suitable for nonnative speakers? It just sometimes seems like such a burden to find a vivid answer for controversial grammatical issues. Thanks in advance!