# Why a sentence can use '-ing' verb without prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar

- A regular expression is a pattern **describing** a certain amount of text.

From my understanding, the correct syntax should be -

- A regular expression is a pattern **that describes** a certain amount of text.

So why the first sentence is correct?

Comment: You need to use subject–auxiliary inversion when asking questions.

Comment: See also [What is a noun-modifying clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971) (and others; the whiz-deletion school still exists).

Comment: "You see that guy over there eating a piece of pie?"

Comment: Why is it correct? Because of a thousand years of grammaticalisation. Just like every other aspect of grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1] *A regular expression is a pattern* [*describing a certain amount of text*].

[2] *A regular expression is a pattern* [*that describes a certain amount of text*

In both examples the expression in brackets is a modifier in noun phrase structure, where it modifies "pattern".

They are semantically similar, but in [1] it's a gerund-participial clause, while in [2] it's a relative clause.

We don't call [1] a relative clause since there is no possibility of it containing a relative phrase (cf. *a pattern which describing a certain of ...).