# present participle in there be sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis, present-participles, participial-phrases, whiz-deletion

"There is a man sitting under the tree. "
How to explain the "sitting" grammatically?

Comment: The actual answer is found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/551880/349876); this is a matter of modification in the noun phrase (here, postmodification).