# To keep or not to keep THAT is the question

Tags: writing-style, that

Is it discretionary to drop "that" from the sentence below (and similar sentences)?

*The movie's script was so bad it blew*.

Or am I flouting some rule of grammar here?

Thank you!

Comment: This is very basic question; one that would be more suited to the learners's site ELL

Comment: Sorry for posting it here then. Could you please provide a short answer now that I have posted it here?

Comment: Here’s a question with an excellent answer (John Lawler’s). https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a noun modifying clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause)

Comment: Thank you, Xanne

Comment: The subordinator "that" is optional here though its omission is characteristic of informal style.

Comment: Thank you, BillJ!

Comment: @Xanne Lawler's answer was about relative clauses, but the subordinate clause in the OP's example here is a declarative content clause functioning as a complement.

Comment: That's right, BillJ.