# Can I omit Relative Phrase in a Non-restrictive Relative Clause?

Tags: non-restrictive

**Example**

> "Ms. Desai bought shares in FTC International,  manufacturer of a wide range of smartphone accessories."

[image]
From Santa TOEIC (WEB SERVICE)

**Hypothesis**

- "which is a" is omitted before "manufacturer".
- This is a non-restrictive clause.

Comment: I think that you're on the right track. I recommend that you look up "whiz-deletion". Omission of the article before "manufacturer" is fairly common, but I believe that it occurs more in AmE than in BrE. (You should also cite the quotation's source.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, one of my friends from the US said omitting the article is weird. But I will try to look for whiz-deletion.

Comment: I googled whiz-deletion but I could not find a trustworthy source. Can you give me any good resources about it?

Comment: I would look on this site. You could search for the phrase "whiz deletion" (with quotation marks) or for [the tag with that name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiz-deletion). [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971) has a good example of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Ms. Desai bought shares in FTC International,* [*manufacturer of a wide*
> *range of smartphone accessories*].

I wouldn't say this is a non-restrictive construction with the relative phrase omitted.

The bracketed element is non-restrictive, but it's an ascriptive NP supplement, more specifically a 'bare NP', i.e. one with no determiner.

It would be possible to add a determiner: ***a** manufacturer of a wide range of* *smartphone accessories*.

Comment: Note that you could also have plural "manufacturers" instead of singular "manufacturer" in your original sentence.