# Is this a non-finite verb?

Tags: verbs, nonfinite-verbs

"'Sadie's Home' **is** a family-friendly movie *told* from the perspective of a little girl called Sadie."

Is 'told' a non-finite verb here? (past participle)

I believe the main verb is "is", and then "told" is a non-finite verb? My reasoning is that "told" doesn't indicate tense here, because the sentence could be changed to "'Sadie's Home' **was**... told from..."

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes: I'd say that "told from the perspective of a little girl called Sadie" is a past-participial clause modifying the nominal "family-friendly movie". It is semantically similar to the relative clause in "a family-friendly movie that is told from the perspective of a little girl called Sadie"

Comment: Yes, it's a past participle, as you suspect. It's part of a reduced relative clause _(which/that is/was) told from the perspective of a little girl_. We can't tell whether the speaker would have used _which_ or _that_, nor whether they'd have used _is_ or _was_ -- when words get deleted, information inevitably gets lost. But [_Whiz_-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) works anyway, producing the non-finite verb.

Comment: I reject the term 'reduced relative clause'. I don't want to be positing a deleted verb. Just because the expression "told from the perspective of a little girl called Sadie" is modifying the nominal "family-friendly movie" it doesn't make it some kind of relative clause. It's not; it's a non-finite past-participial clause.

Answer (score 3):

> *Sadie's Home' is* [*a family-friendly movie told from the perspective of*
> a *little girl called Sadie*].

Yes: "told" is a non-finite (past participle) verb and *told from the perspective of a little girl called Sadie* is a past-participial clause modifying the nominal "family-friendly movie".

It is semantically similar to a relative clause: compare *a family-friendly movie that* *is told from the perspective of a little girl called Sadie*.

Past-participial modifiers are 'bare passives', as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase in complement function.

It is not analysed as some kind of relative clause as there is no possibility of it containing a relative phrase (compare the ungrammatical *a family-friendly movie which told from the perspective of a little girl called Sadie*).

Comment: In traditional grammar terms, it is a reduced *passive* relative clause: *[that **is**] told* (not *[that] told*).

Comment: @TinfoilHat I said in my answer that it's passive. As for 'reduced relative clause, why would I want to posit a deleted verb?

Answer (score 0):

The term is one I never learned, but the concept I do know. I think your reasoning is sound, and I would say you are correct.
“Told” is a past tense, yet is unaffected by any other part of the sentence, and could not be changed to another tense. It’s a contraction of “which is told,” where the verb and its connected words function as  the second adjective describing the movie.